# 'join' MongodDB collections with a for loop?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

This is a very simplified version of my query.

Is it acceptable / efficient to join the two collections for the client with the use of for loops?

There could be up to 2,000 books, which also means there could be an equal number of favorite books per user in the favoriteBooksCollection.

```
return favoriteBooksCollection
.find({user: current_userId})
.then(function(favorites){

    var bookIds = favorites.map(function (a) {
        return a.bookId
    };

    return BooksCollection
    .find({_id : {$in: bookIds}})
    .sort({timestamp: -1})
    .then(function(books){

     for(var i = 0; i < books.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < favorites.length; j++){
          if(favorites[j].bookId  == books[i]._id){

           //'join' user's myRating to book document here
            books[i].userRating = favorites[j].myRating;  

           };
        };    
    };

      // return books array of objects with newly added UserRating property
      return books;

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within MongoDB's aggregation API you'll find [the `$lookup` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) which is for joins:

**`orders`**:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc", "price" : 12, "quantity" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 3  }
```

**`inventory`**:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "sku" : "abc", description: "product 1", "instock" : 120 }
{ "_id" : 2, "sku" : "def", description: "product 2", "instock" : 80 }
{ "_id" : 3, "sku" : "ijk", description: "product 3", "instock" : 60 }
{ "_id" : 4, "sku" : "jkl", description: "product 4", "instock" : 70 }
{ "_id" : 5, "sku" : null, description: "Incomplete" }
{ "_id" : 6 }
```

#### Join:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "inventory",
          localField: "item",
          foreignField: "sku",
          as: "inventory_docs"
        }
   }
])
```

But if you don't want or can't use the aggregation api, then I suggest you use `forEach` instead of `for`, it's way cleaner and you still get the index.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking into $lookup, but saw the possible drawbacks with sharding. I may still go with this as of now, since I am not sharding. Just trying to learn best practices still.

Comment: @NoobSter You're right about the sharding. This and the `forEach` are the only two ways to perform joins in MongoDB